# Como escanear equipos que estén en red en VBA.NET?

Tags: vb.net

Necesito saber si puedo o como puedo saber informacion de los equipos que estan en mi red por ejemplo. MAC,Nombre etc....
Alguna librería que sea útil o algo....
Gracias de antemano!.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Esta pregunta se considera basada en opiniones y puede llegar a ser cerrada. Por favor mira los enlaces que te deje en el comentario anterior.